# Check if items in one dictionary are absent from another

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
d ={0: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '15.08.2021 17:30', 'team1': '1. FC Köln', 'team2': 'Hertha BSC Berlin', 'h_tore': '3', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '},
    1: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'Arminia Bielefeld', 'team2': 'SC Freiburg', 'h_tore': '0', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    2: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'VfL Wolfsburg', 'team2': 'VfL Bochum', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    3: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FC Augsburg', 'team2': 'TSG Hoffenheim', 'h_tore': '0', 'a_tore': '4', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '},
    4: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'VfB Stuttgart', 'team2': 'Greuther Fürth', 'h_tore': '5', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    5: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': '1. FC Union Berlin', 'team2': 'Bayer Leverkusen', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '},
    6: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '14.08.2021 18:30', 'team1': 'Borussia Dortmund', 'team2': 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 'h_tore': '5', 'a_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '3', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '},
    7: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '15.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FSV Mainz 05', 'team2': 'RB Leipzig', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    8: {'spieltag': '1. Spieltag:', 'tag': 'Fr', 'd_u': '13.08.2021 20:30', 'team1': 'Borussia M´gladbach', 'team2': 'Bayern München', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '}}

m ={0: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'Fr', 'd_u': '27.08.2021 20:30', 'team1': 'Borussia Dortmund', 'team2': 'TSG Hoffenheim', 'h_tore': '3', 'a_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    1: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '28.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'VfB Stuttgart', 'team2': 'SC Freiburg', 'h_tore': '-', 'a_tore': '-', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '-', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '-', 'absage': ' '},
    2: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '28.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'Arminia Bielefeld', 'team2': 'Eintracht Frankfurt', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '1', 'absage': ' '},
    3: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '28.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': '1. FC Köln', 'team2': 'VfL Bochum', 'h_tore': '2', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    4: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '28.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FC Augsburg', 'team2': 'Bayer Leverkusen', 'h_tore': '1', 'a_tore': '4', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '2', 'absage': ' '},
    5: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '28.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': 'FSV Mainz 05', 'team2': 'Greuther Fürth', 'h_tore': '3', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    6: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'Sa', 'd_u': '28.08.2021 18:30', 'team1': 'Bayern München', 'team2': 'Hertha BSC Berlin', 'h_tore': '5', 'a_tore': '0', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    7: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '29.08.2021 15:30', 'team1': '1. FC Union Berlin', 'team2': 'Borussia M´gladbach', 'h_tore': '2', 'a_tore': '1', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '2', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '0', 'absage': ' '},
    8: {'Spieltag': '3', 'tag': 'So', 'd_u': '29.08.2021 17:30', 'team1': 'VfL Wolfsburg', 'team2': 'RB Leipzig', 'h_tore': '-', 'a_tore': '-', 'halbzeit_h_tore': '-', 'halbzeit_a_tore': '-', 'absage': ' '}}
```

For each item in `d`, how can I check if the item is absent in `m` and if absent perform some operation?

Comment: It looks like none of the items in ‘d’ match those in ‘m’, so I expect your comprehension to be empty which will always be False. Try ‘print([False for k,v2 ...])’

Comment: What is your thought process with that to begin with? I mean you're comparing two matchdays which are enumerated and contain a date so by default it's impossible that they are equal. So quamrana is correct v1==v2 is a condition that is never triggered and thus your lists remain empty, hence always false. But what do you intent to do with this to begin with?

Comment: Try ‘print([False for k,v2 ...])’ is still False

Comment: I want to compary if the two value dicts are the same, and return True if not. How is any(False for k,v2  in m.items() if v1 == v2) not triggered v1==v2 should be False but with the 'any(False...' it schould be true.

Comment: It doesn't matter wether you use `True` or `False` in the generator expression in `any()`, because the result is always empty: `v1 == v2` is always `False`, therefore the `if`-condition prevents any element. Look at `print(any([]))`, which is essentially the same.

Comment: I did this ‘print([False for k,v2 ...])’  now I get <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000019B93608190>

Comment: How can I check if any element d is in m, return false if it is and return true if not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that none of the values (dictionaries) in `d` have a match in `m`. Here is some simpler data with a matching value:

```
d = {
  1: {'type': 'star', 'name': 'Sun'},
  2: {'type': 'natural satellite', 'name': 'Moon'}
}

m = {
  1: {'type': 'natural satellite', 'name': 'Moon'},
  2: {'type':'planet', 'name': 'Earth'}
}
```

Solution:

```
for item in d.items():
  if item not in m.items(): do_operation()
```

Remember that the `not in` operator does comparisons internally.

Comment: I need to check if one item is equal to anyone in the dict and if it is not I ne to peform a operation, If I have 2 dict with 3 different values this operation would be peformed 9 times. But I need it peform only the 3 times.

Comment: Edited answer (and question) based on your comment. This is a pretty basic piece of logic. I think you may need to brush up on your Python data structures.  Nice places to start: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html and https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq .

Comment: Thanks I am a beginner just started a month ago.

Comment: It's cool. Get familiar with the Python docs to see all the fun things you can do with it. It's a good idea to understand what your code truly does.